# What's wrong with this induction? (Runtime analysis of standard polynomial long division)

Tags: polynomials, induction, fake-proofs

In my studies for my Bachelor's thesis, I've gone through a runtime analysis of plain vanilla polynomial long division, i.e. I wanted to prove the statement:

*Let $f,\,g \in F[X] \land g\neq 0$ where $F$ is a field. Define $n:=\deg (f)\vee \deg (g)$. Then it takes $O(n^2 + 1)$ field operations to determine $q,\,r \in K[X]$ s.th.
$$
f = qg + r\,,\quad\deg(r) < \deg(g)
$$*

**NOTE**: I've added the '$+ 1$' in the big-Oh notation for the border case that both degrees are zero (since afaik, $O(0)$ would mean zero field operations, which wouldn't be true).

However, I am not sure why the following *proof-attemp, that it takes $O(n+1)$ operations is wrong (I have some idea, which I will mention after this proof-attempt, but I can't see how this idea breaks this induction).

> **Proof** We attempt induction over $d:=\deg(f)$. The statement is
>
> **S$(d)$**
>   *Let $f,\,g \in F[X] \land g\neq 0$ where $F$ is a field. Put $\,\mathbf{d} := \deg (f)$ and define $n:=\mathbf{d} \vee \deg (g)$.
>   Then it takes $O(\mathbf{n} + 1)$ field operations to determine $q,\,r
> > \in K[X]$ s.th. $$ f = qg + r\,,\quad\deg(r) < \deg(g) $$*
>
> **Base case** Let $d = 0$. Then we have  $ 0 = d = \deg (f) <= \deg(g) $ , since $g \neq 0$. Hence, $n = \deg(g)$ .   If $n = \deg(g) = 0$,
>   then take $$ q:=fg^{-1},\,r:=0 $$ and we are done in a constant amount
>   of field operations, so in $O(1) = O(n+1)$.   If $\deg(g) > 0 = \deg
> > (g) $, then $$ q:=0,\,r:=f $$ also do the job in $O(n) = O(n+1)$ field
>   operations. Hence, **S$(0)$** holds true.
>
> **Inductive step** Now, let $d > 0$ and assume that **S$(\sigma)$** holds true for all $0 \leq \sigma < d$. As in the base case, if $\deg(g) > \deg (f)$, we are done in a constant amount of field operations.   If $\deg(g) \leq \deg (f)$, then put $q_0 := l_f l_g X^{\deg(f) - \deg(g)}$, where $l_f,\,l_g$ are the leading coefficients of $f$ and $g$.
>   Then $$ \tilde f := f - q_0 g $$ is calculated in $O(\deg (g)) = O(\deg (f)) = O(n) = O(n+1)$ field operations, because we only
>   multiply $g$ by a monomial and $\deg (\tilde f) < \deg (f) = d$.
>
> Induction hypothesis (**$S(\deg (\tilde f))$** now yields $q_1$ and $r$ with $\deg (r) < \deg
> > (g)$, s.th. $$ \tilde f = q_1 g + r $$ in $O(\deg (\tilde f) \vee \deg
> > (g) + 1) = O(n + 1)$ field operations. Then, $f = (q_0 + q_1) g + r$,
>   and since $q_1,\, q_0$ necessarily are bounded by $n$ in their
>   degrees, $q_0 + q_1$ is also calculated in $O(n + 1)$ field
>   operations.   Since we have a sequence of procedures that take
>   $O(n+1)$ field operations, we are done.

Now, this obviously goes wrong somewhere.

My idea is that in the base case, we never have to consider $\deg(f) > \deg(g)$, in which case we would need $O(n^2)$ field operations in the worst case. However, I don't see anything wrong with the inductive proof itself (I'm probably blind in some way):

We have a statement **S** that depends on our induction variable, we prove the base case **S$(0)$**, we do the inductive step **S$(\sigma)$** $, \sigma < d \rightarrow$ **S$(d)$**.

Comment: Just to be clear, what is the ∨ symbol? Does it mean max or min?

Comment: The other thing is, this is quite hard to follow since you are mixing the time complexity analysis together with the actual algorithm. Try separating the algorithm (perhaps write down a sequence of polynomials it calculates), then try analysing how long it takes to compute each element in the sequence from the last one.

Comment: @Joppy $\vee$ stands for $\max$. About your other comment: The statement I wanted to prove doesn't refer to any specific algorithmic procedure, and neither does the inductive hypothesis. So I don't have to stick to any algorithm. You could view this as a constructive proof and forget thinking about algorithms when checking it. I know how $O(n^2)$ comes about if I don't do this inductively, but I don't see where this inductive proof goes wrong.

Comment: @Joppy I think I've found the error, and it *does* relate closely to what you've mentioned about mixing complexity analysis with an actual algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the error. First off, in itself, the statement and the proof aren't wrong. The problem is, that they're not stating what I meant to prove.

Essentially, in all the statements I use/want to prove, $f$ and $g$ are fixed, and so, $n$ is fixed as well, and the runtime-related statements become pretty much something among the lines of

> *If we have two polynomials $f$ and $g$, $g \neq 0$, then we can calculate the polynomials $q$ and $r$ (as mentioned in the equation
>   for polynomial long division) with some finite amount of field
>   operations.*

because $n$ becomes a constant, so that $O(n)$ means constant time. And if we consider a fixed input, the algorithm will of course always run in the same amount of time, since it's a constant-input-algorithm.

I initially wasn't careful enough wording the statement to be proven. Here's something closer to what I should have written instead:

> Let $F$ be a field. Consider the 'standard' polynomial long division algorithm
>
> $$
> A: F[X] \times F[X] \setminus \left\{0\right\} \longrightarrow {F[X]}^2
>   $$
>   that uses $(f,\,g)$ to determine $(q,\,r)$ such that $f = qg + r$ and $\deg(r) < \deg (g)$.
>   Define $n(f,\,g):=\deg (f)\vee \deg (g)$ as the input size function.
>
> Then $A$ has worst-case complexity $O(n^2 + 1)$ in terms of field operations, i.e. if
>   $$
> \rho_A: F[X] \times F[X] \setminus \left\{0\right\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}
> $$
>   describes the amount of field operations $\rho_A(f,\,g)$ needed for the computation $A(f,\,g)$, then for any sequence $(f_l,\,g_l)$ of polynomial tuples such that
>   $$
> \lim_l(n(f_l,\,g_l)) = \infty
> $$
>   (i.e. if any of the sequence projections is unbounded in the polynomial degree), we have
>   $$
> \rho_A(f_l,\,g_l) = O(n(f_l,\,g_l)^2 + 1)\;\text{as}\;l\rightarrow \infty
> $$

This more precise formulation also makes it more clear why the proof in the question was misleading.

Essentially, the root problem was misuse of big-Oh notation.